# boost::shared_ptr parent <-> child communication

Tags: c++, boost, parent-child, shared-ptr

I am using boost::shared_ptr to organize my pointer data in my game engine.

I tried to make a very short example to show my problem:

```
class CSceneNode
{
public:
    CSceneNode(CScene *p) : parent(p) {}

    void foo() {
        parent->notifyThatFooWasCalledOnMe(my_shared_ptr_version_of_this???);
    };

    CScene *parent;
};

class CScene
{
public:
    void addNode() {
        nodes.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<CSceneNode>(new CSceneNode(this)));
    }

    void notifyThatFooWasCalledOnMe(boost::shared_ptr<CSceneNode> node) {
        foo_was_called[node] = true;
    }

    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<CSceneNode> > nodes;
    std::map<boost::shared_ptr<CSceneNode>, bool> foo_was_called;
};
```

Thus the problem is:
CScene creates CSceneNode's and owns these in boost::shared_ptr's into a list.

Now the child needs to notify the parent of a change. This is easy, as I passed the pointer of CScene onto CSceneNode, the node knows its parent. As the node will not live longer than the parent, it is ok to just pass a pointer.

But the parent also needs to know who it is that calls it back, and there's the problem. The parent doesn't know the raw pointers, it only knows shared pointers, so the only way to find out which child is calling is searching over all nodes to find that one with the same raw pointer inside, or create another map mapping from raw pointer to shared_ptr. This last one then needs extra maintenance when a node is deleted. I could also pass the shared_ptr to the child itself to help it send itself back, but that seems stupid.

Can anyone tell me what to do? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now the child needs to notify the parent of a change.

Remove this requirement, and the whole problem collapses... as well as your cyclic dependency.

You might consider an event-based system instead, or state polling.

Comment: Speed is of utmost importance so polling is not an option. Event based will make this way too complicated as it are lots of childs which need to notify the parent. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @scippie: Polling need not impact "speed". An event-based system is usually _less_ complicated than alternatives. Much better than a tangled web of `shared_ptr` dependencies. I'd reconsider because I think your rationales are pretty flimsy.

Comment: I have thought this over very well and I think you are right, my shader_ptr's were indeed overly used. I have simplified the parent-child-relationship but have kept the safety of the shared_ptr's for where it is needed. I also marked your answer as the correct answer although it is not the answer to my question, but just because others with the same problem should read your answer too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might want to use [enable_shared_from_this<>](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html), which is a way for an object to be aware of its own shared_ptr<> ownership.

So...

```
class CSceneNode : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<CSceneNode> // <- (1)
{ 
public:
    CSceneNode(CScene *p) : parent(p) {}

    void foo() {
        parent->notifyThatFooWasCalledOnMe(shared_from_this()); // <- (2)
    };

    CScene *parent;
};
```

Comment: I think this is a helpful tip, I didn't know that this existed! Thanks!

Comment: Although your answer was the exact answer to my question, I think Tomalak gave me a better answer. I followed his advice and did not use your sollution. But it is indeed, the answer to my question and I am grateful to have learnt about it thanks to you.

Comment: @scippie - no problem, and thanks for the explanation.  Glad to have helped in any case.

Answer (score 0):

What about to override predicate less in your map

```
std::map<boost::shared_ptr<CSceneNode>, bool, MyLess>
```

You could compare by pointer, so to locate pointer you just need create temp instance of shared_ptr from pointer.

Comment: I don't think that that's quite safe to work with... With this you will have two totally different shader_ptr's pointing to the same address. If this second one stops existing, the object is deleted while the other shared_ptr doesn't want that.

Comment: @scippie - agree, that is why instead of [] usage of `insert` is much more safe - since insert returns pair if new value has been inserted or just existing one returned.